# How to pass json array under request body using simply json

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am using below code to automate REST API.
Please help me to understand how can I put whole json data for sample data mentioned below as the input has arrays whereas till now I used flat jsons without arrays

```java
Method Dummy()
{
    RestAssured.baseURI ="http://mydummyURL";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("id", "THAILAND"); //Issue is with this code 
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
    Response response = request.post("/EndPoint");
}
```

where the json body looks like this

```js
{
    "tag1": "value1",
    "tag2": "value2",
    "tag3": {
        "tag31": "value31",
        "tag32": "value32"
    },
    "tag4": [{
            "domainName": "ABC",
            "domainId": "123ABC123",
            "domainGUID": "TestMyDomain"
        },
        {
            "domainName": "XYZ",
            "domainId": "123XYZ123",
            "domainGUID": "TestMyDomain"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to put your XML to file, and then only read this file to `JSONObject` and then pass it to the body using `.toJSONString()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> array= new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    JSONObject json= new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("key", "value");// your json
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    array.add(json);
    String printjsonarray= array.toString();// pass this into the request
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

//Create a Java Class for the variables inside array.

```
JsonArrayData tag4paramVal1 = new JsonArrayData("ABC","123ABC123","TestMyDomain");
JsonArrayData tag4paramVal2 = new JsonArrayData("XYZ","123XYZ123","TestMyDomain");

    Object[] tag4ValArray = {tag4paramVal1,tag4paramVal2};

    String reqJson = null;
    List<String> tag4Data = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Object obj:tag4ValArray){

        reqJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        System.out.println(reqJson);
        tag4Data.add(reqJson);

    }

    System.out.println(tag4Data);

    HashMap<String,List<String>> finalReq = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    finalReq.put("\"tag4\":",tag4Data);


    String finalreqString = finalReq.toString();
    System.out.println(finalreqString);

    finalreqString = finalreqString.replace('=', ' ');
    System.out.println(finalreqString);
```

//Use the above String as a parameter to POST request. You will get your desired JSON array .

//JsonArrayData class code

public class JsonArrayData {

```
String domainName;
String domainId;
String domainGUID;

public JsonArrayData(String domainName,String domainId,String domainGUID){

    this.domainName = domainName;
    this.domainId = domainId;
    this.domainGUID = domainGUID;

}

public String getDomainName() {
    return domainName;
}

public void setDomainName(String domainName) {
    this.domainName = domainName;
}

public String getDomainId() {
    return domainId;
}

public void setDomainId(String domainId) {
    this.domainId = domainId;
}

public String getDomainGUID() {
    return domainGUID;
}

public void setDomainGUID(String domainGUID) {
    this.domainGUID = domainGUID;
}
```

}